# Nim: How to iterate over a slice?

Tags: for-loop, iterator, nim-lang

I'm puzzled by the following observation. On the one hand, this works:

```
for i in 5..10:
  echo i
```

But as soon as I store the slice in a variable, I can no longer iterate over it, i.e., this fails:

```
var slice = 5..10
for i in slice:
  echo i
```

The error is `type mismatch: got (Slice[system.int])`, and apparently there is no overloaded signature of the `system.items` iterator for `Slice[T]`. This raises the questions:

- Why does it work at all in the first case?
- Is there a workaround to iterate over a slice in the second case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `for i in 5..10:` you invoke the iterator [`..` (doc)](http://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#...i,S,T), which is just an alias for countup. Since this is an inline iterator it transforms the for-loop into a while-loop over the values 5 to 10. But inline iterators cannot be assigned to a variable, other than closure iterators.

With `var slice = 5..10` you invoke the proc [`..` (doc)](http://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#..,T,T), which generates a `Slice(a: 5, b: 10)`. But Slices don't have a default `items` iterator defined.

You could iterate from `slice.a` to `slice.b`, like this:

```
var slice = 5..10
for i in slice.a .. slice.b:
  echo i
```

Since this is not very nice, the proper solution is to define your own `items` iterator, like this:

```
iterator items*[T](s: Slice[T]): T =
  for i in s.a .. s.b:
    yield i

var slice = 5..10
for i in slice:
  echo i
```

Since this seems pretty reasonable to me, I made a pull request to have this included in the system module: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/pull/2449